# oidc-client isLoggedIn()

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

What is the most concise and accurate way to determine `isLoggedIn()` with odic-client?

Much like the [Angualr2 example](https://github.com/jmurphzyo/Angular2OidcClient/blob/master/src/app/shared/services/auth.service.ts#L71) my first method was:

```
// return true if user (token) exists.
public isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.userManager.getUser().then(user => !!user);
}
```

Then to handle expired tokens:

```
// return true if user (token) exists and not expired.
public isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.userManager.getUser().then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            return false;
        }
        return !user.expired;
    });
}
```

A requirement of my app is that it not show the user as logged in if the OP has revoked the session so, following the logic [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/a91ea24d54f438d0381c448045bd7e9786965766/src/SessionMonitor.js#L93), my next method was:

```
// return true if user (token) and session (cookie) exists and sub matches and not expired.
public async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    const session = await this.userManager.querySessionStatus().catch(() => null);
    const user = await this.userManager.getUser();
    if (!user || !session) {
        return false;
    }
    if (session.sub !== user.profile.sub) {
        return false;
    }
    return !user.expired;
}
```

Now I'm noticing that if I start my app with an expired token silent renew gets a new token with the session cookie after my `isLoggedIn()` logic so, I have a false negative. There is the `userLoaded` event but that dosn't fire if the token is still valid.

Comment: If the app started with an expired token, user.expired will be true right?

Comment: wow, that helps thank you